# Windows 7 can't be loaded after installing Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: boot, windows, grub2, windows-7

I use a MacBook Pro 8,2. First of all I installed Mac OS X, then Windows 7 on sde4, then Ubuntu on sde5 and swap on sde5. After installing Ubuntu Windows 7 isn't loaded when I choose it in GRUB. Windows Boot Manager shows the following message:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc0000225

  Info: An error occurred while  attempting to load the boot configuration data.
```

What shall I do? Should I try to repair Windows using CD (in this case I think I will damage GRUB) or can I somehow configure GRUB to make it work properly?

Comment: You can run `fixboot` and `fixmbr` from the Windows CD, but this will get rid of GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use the Boot Repair utility provided by the Windows 7 Boot Disk

After doing so, boot up from the Ubuntu live CD and follow [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/113854/17722) instructions to restore grub and fix windows on the mbr