# problems with grub

Tags: grub2

I updated ubuntu and when I restarted this message appeared:
GNU GRUB version 1.99-12ubuntu5
minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. for the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub> and here is where I suppose i must write a command in order to open ubuntu normally, the problem is, what do i put?
please help!!!!

Comment: insert livecd and update grub

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but what is livecd?

Comment: live cd is your ubuntu cd

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/6321/39372

Answer (score 5):

[**BOOT REPAIR DISK**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

> Boot-Repair is a small graphical tool to restore access to Ubuntu and
>   other OS (Windows..).

[image]

**Getting Boot-Repair**

***1st option*** :

*get a CD including Boot-Repair*

> The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to burn one of the following CDs
>   and boot on  it.

1. [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) is a CD starting Boot-Repair automatically. (English only).
2. Boot-Repair is also included in [Ubuntu Secured Remix](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10084551&postcount=1) CDs (multi-languages)

**2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

Either add ‘`ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`’ to your Software Sources via the Software Centre or, for speeds-sake, add it using a new Terminal session:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Using Boot-Repair

**Recommended repair**

launch Boot-Repair from either :
1.the dash (Unity)

2.System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Gnome)

3.typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

> Then try "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, reboot
>   and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

**Links**

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
2. https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/
3. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10084551&postcount=1
4. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/