# Installing multiple ubuntu partitions on same machine without corrupting GRUB

Tags: grub2, partitioning

I had only ubuntu installed on my pc, but I felt like adding another ubuntu (same version) partition so I could have one just for work/study and another one just for personal generic use.

I installed it and it worked out okay, but I found I needed more space on the new created Ubuntu partition, so I booted up from the Live CD, and used GParted to move/shrink/grow the partitions as the Ubuntu's tutorials suggested it was pretty straightforward. But in doing all this I messed up with Grub, so when I start my system it shows:

error: unknow filesystem
grub rescue>

What would be the easiest way to recover it so I could have both partitions working? Btw, it wouldn't be a problem for me to lose the partitions if it's the shortest/easiest way.

Thanks in advance.

---

Ok, so I tried all the grub rescue's commands which were listed here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) , none of them worked. Also, when I entered 'ls' , it would list several (hd0, msdosX) instead of several (hd0, X) . All the Ubuntu's partitions are inside an extended one. If I delete this partition and overwrite it with a new ext4 partition, using the LiveCD, and then use it to install Ubuntu, would it fix grub?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: The preferred method of repairing gurb is to use boot-repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . There is nothing wrong with the command line tools in the answer linked by tachyons, just most people find a graphical tool easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problems with grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/113849/problems-with-grub)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to learn `grub`'s prompt: in grub menu type `e` to 'edit', then `Ctrl+c` to enter `grub`'s command line.

Now, you can enter `root (hd<Tab>` and grub will display possible devices; having typed (for example) `root (hg0,<Tab>` you can see possible partiions.

The key point is that you can alter grub's configuration before booting the entry: I believe you need to change `root` to correct its value before boot. You can not "pollute" your original `menu.lst` (or `grub.cfg`) in this way.

Note that `root` is that place where `grub` directory is located --- the directory where grub's configuration and `stage*` and filesystem related etc-etc files are --- typically it is `/boot/` (`grub/` is under it). In my case I can type in grub command line `root (hd0,1)/boot/grub<Tab>` and see all files needed by `grub`.

After booting you wil be able to change/correct grub's configuration.